# What could be causing my program to go over a function twice even though it should be exiting after running over it once?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a game of rock, paper, scissors, and I am having issues figuring out why my program is reiterating over a function twice when it it supposed to go over it once and then start back at the beginning due to a `while` loop.

Here is the function that is causing the problem (unnecessary information filtered out):

```
def playRps():  # Compares the choices and determines who won the game
    game = "".join([playerAction, computerAction])

    outcomes = {
        "rr": tied,
        "pp": tied,
        "ss": tied,
        "rp": playerLoss,
        "ps": playerLoss,
        "sr": playerLoss,
        "rs": playerWin,
        "pr": playerWin,
        "sp": playerWin,
    }

    if playerAction == "q":
        return False

    else:
        action = outcomes.get(game)
        if action:
            action()
        else:
            print("Invalid input!")
```

You can find the entire `functions.py` file [here.](https://github.com/LiterallyJohnny/rock_paper_scissors/blob/main/functions.py)

Here is the `main.py` file that calls the functions and runs the program (unnecessary information filtered out):

```
while True:
    if functions.playerScore != 0 or functions.computerScore != 0:
        functions.scores()

    playGame = str(input('Would you like to play "Rock, Paper, Scissors"? (Y/n): '))

    if playGame == "y":
        while True:
            functions.playerChoice()
            functions.computerChoice()
            functions.playRps()
            if not functions.playRps():
                break

    elif playGame == "n":
        print("Terminating program...")
        quit()

    else:
        print("Unknown input. Please enter a valid answer.")
        continue
```

You can find the entire `main.py` file [here.](https://github.com/LiterallyJohnny/rock_paper_scissors/blob/main/main.py)

Well, the program appears to go to `actions = outcome.get(game)` in `functions.py` as expected when you don't input `q`. Then, it goes to the `main.py` file and validates the outcome at `if not functions.playRps():`.

For some reason, it then proceeds to go *back* to `functions.py` and it ends up back at `actions = outcome.get(game)`, which adds a second point. *Then* it goes *back* to `main.py` and then it hits the `break` right after the `if not functions.playRps():`.

It shouldn't be hitting be repeating `playRps()` twice, nor should it be hitting the `break` in `main.py` when I didn't input `q` as the player response. It should go *back* to the `playerChoice()` function in `main.py` due to the `while` loop, so the player could make their choice.

The `while` loop in `main.py` shouldn't be broken at all unless the player enters `q` when the `playerChoice()` function is called.

My question to you guys is:

- Why is the program repeating the `playRps()` function twice, and why is the `while` loop in `main.py` where the functions are called being broken even though the player never entered `q` when the `playerChoice()` function is called?

Comment: `if action: action()` should probably be `if action: return action()`.

Comment: @chepner nope, same results.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is being called the second time because you call the function again in your `if statement`:

```
functions.playRps() # call 1
if not functions.playRps(): # call 2
    break
```

You should set a variable to the result of that function so that you can evaluate it in the `if statement` without calling it again:

```
result = functions.playRps()
if not result:
    break
```

Comment: Yeah, this seemed to be it. I did have to change a few things. I had to make `playRps` return `True` in `functions.py`, and I had to use `if result: break` in `main.py`. It appears to work now. Thanks for you help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Enjoy :)